# SPARQL QuadPattern

Tags: sparql

In SPARQL a `QuadPattern` is [defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rQuadPattern) as

```
QuadPattern ::= '{' Quads '}'
Quads       ::= TriplesTemplate? ( QuadsNotTriples '.'? TriplesTemplate? )*
```

From this I understand that a `QuadPattern` can be empty. But I can not understand the reason. Whats the purpose of an empty `QuadPattern`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Antoine Zimmermann points out just because the syntax allows it doesn't mean it is meaningful.

In this case I believe it was done to keep the grammar within a certain constraint and to simplify it.  If you don't allows `Quads` to be empty then you'd have to redefine the `QuadPattern` rule as so:

```
QuadPattern ::= '{' '}' | '{' Quads '}'
```

Which just adds unnecessary complication particularly when you are using a parser generator

Answer (score 2):

With an empty quad pattern, you can, for instance, delete the default graph completely:

```
DELETE WHERE { }
```

But the fact that something is allowed by the syntax does not necessarily mean that there was a deliberate choice to allow a specific pattern. It may be, in some cases, that it is more convenient to define things in a more generic way.

Comment: Oops, you're right! However, I can't delete it as you cross reference it in your answer :P